# Булева алгебра

Tags: c++

Начал изучать с/с++, и там нужно знать все логические операции в с++ (типа `&&`, `*=` и т.д.), подскажите, где можно найти все разъяснения по этому и, желательно, с примерами и подробным описанием.

Comment: я про все операции а не про  штуки
и желательно с примером

Comment: логических операций в с++ всего 3, остальный побитовые, или я не прав?

Comment: Вы не поверите, логических - всего 3 =) XOR, например, - уже комбинация.

\*= - это вообще умножение %)

Comment: Если Вы про операции типа *=, +=, -=, /= и т.д, то это не есть логические операции.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` - логическое "И" - `true && true => true` в остальных случаях `false`

пример 1:

```
2 двери, если хотя бы одна закрыта вы не можете пройти, если открыты обе, пройти можно
|    |
 /    /  <= ☺
|    |
```

пример 2:

```
public bool Condition(bool flag)
{
   return flag;
}
main()
{
    bool trigger = true;
    if(Condition(trigger) && Condition(trigger))
    {
        //условие выполняется только в этом случае
    }
}
```

---

`||` - логическое "ИЛИ" - `false || false => false` в остальных случаях `true`

пример 3:

```
2 двери, если хотя бы одна открыта вы можете пройти, если закрыты обе, пройти нельзя
|
 /
|    <=☺
 /
|
```

пример 4:

```
public bool Condition(bool flag)
{
   return flag;
}
main()
{
   bool trigger = false;
   if(Condition(trigger) || Condition(trigger))
   {
       //условие не выполняется только в этом случае
   }
}
```

---

`!` - логическое "НЕ" - `!true => false; !false => true`

`==` - логическое равенство `true == true; false == false`

`!=` - логическое неравенство `true != !true; false != true`

на Wiki [Логическая операция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Логическая_операция)